# Apache-Airflow UI page size wont change

Tags: python-3.x, etl, airflow

I was trying to change the page_size from airflow.cfg but nothing happens!
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/7c9b44dbfc72df951aadbda006229977beb6d47c/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L324

I have change the value to :
page_size = 70
but the page size still remaining the same

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you kill the WebServer processes and then restart the WebServer (`airflow webserver` command on CLI) after updating `airflow.cfg`?

Comment: It has changed after restarting thank you for reminder